# operation on set proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, magma

Consider the operation ⊥ defined by placing, for every $x,y\in Z$
$x⊥y=x+|y|$, Check Associativity and Commutativity. Is there a Identity element in $Z$?
My proof:
Associativity
$x⊥(y⊥z)=(x⊥y)⊥z$
$x⊥(y⊥z)=x+|y+|z||$
$(x⊥y)⊥z=(x+|y|)+|z|=x+|y|+|z|\not=x+|y+|z||$
Commutativity
$x⊥y=y⊥x$
$x⊥y=x+|y|$
$y⊥x=y+|x|\not=x+|y|$
Identity element
$x⊥e=e⊥x=x$
$x⊥e=x+|e|=x\Rightarrow e=0?$
$e⊥x=0+|x|\not=x$
so no condition has been met?

Comment: You might want to use specific examples for $x, y,$ and $z$ to "witness" that equality does not in fact hold, but other than minor detail your work looks sound.

Comment: I'd put that even stronger: you really should provide concrete counterexamples.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).